# Frame layout inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working in a Fragment. it contains 2 Buttons and a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="fragments.Fragment_Book_A_Cam">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_Public"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/red"
            android:text="Public Jobs "
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_Active"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black"
            android:text="Active Jobs"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Fragment_Jobs_BookACam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to load another Fragment in the FrameLayout on a Button click and don't want to replace the main FrameLayout.

All the methods I have used either crash or replace the main Fragment.

```
bt_Public.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      //                fragment = new Fragment_MyCloudVideo();
      //                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ;
      //                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      //    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment_MyVideos, fragment);

      //                fragmentTransaction.commit();

      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      Fragment_Public_Jobs fragment = new Fragment_Public_Jobs();
      fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("xyz");
      fragmentTransaction.hide(Fragment_Book_A_Cam.this);
      fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
      fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You never seem to use the `Fragment_Jobs_BookACam` FrameLayout  id

If you want to show Fragments inside Fragments, you need to use the method to get the child FragmentManager

Comment: could you please bring an example?

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct the errors present in your xml file and try replace() method of fragmentTransaction instead add().